# Error 500 while modify data in laravel with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel, controller

I get `Error 500` while doing some change data and update it when using `ajax` in `Laravel 7`

This is `ajax` code :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('#likePost').click(function (e){
            var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '{{ url('/ajax-post-like') }}',
                data: { request: post_id },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

`CSRF` token checked and its working!
Routes checked and its working!
And I can get data from controller when code is :

```
   public function PostLike(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::find($request);
    return response()->json($post);
}
```

But it dose not work when I'm trying to return data like this :

```
    public function PostLike(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::find($request);
    $like = $post->like_count;
    return response()->json($like);
}
```

And when use `$post->like_count`, got `Error 500` in console.
How can I work with database with `ajax` and update `like_count`

Comment: Do you have a column "like_count" on your post table ? If not you will need to change it like that :  $post = Post::withCount('like')->find($request); and I think it should be  $post = Post::find($request->input('request'));

Comment: Can you look at your network tab in your browser and watch for this api call. You can then preview the response of it and get more additional info, probably an exception as well.

Comment: You should be able to see the error in the logs, because 500 means that something went wrong in your backend. My quess would be that `response()->json($like)` is the problem, if `$like` is an integer, because integers are not valid JSON. You should change it to something like `response()->json(['likes' => $like])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define post id in `Find` command.
Please change to this :

```
 public function PostLike(Request $request)
     {
       $post = Post::find($request->post_id);
       $like = $post->like_count;
       return response()->json($like);
    }
```

send `post_id` when you call your `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the key of request :

```
     public function PostLike(Request $request)
     {
       $post = Post::find($request['request']);
       $like = $post->like_count;
       return response()->json($like);
    }
```